# Hive cast from decimal to string truncates the value

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

Conversion of a **decimal** value to **string** using cast() function truncates resulting value, e.g.:

```
hive -e "select cast(cast('0.1629369395016511130907901977737025' as decimal(38,38)) as string)"
```

returns:

```
0.162936939501651113
```

If the **decimal** first converted into **varchar** and later to **string** then result is correct:

```
hive -e "select cast(cast(cast('0.1629369395016511130907901977737025' as decimal(38,38)) as varchar(38)) as string)"
```

returns:

```
0.1629369395016511130907901977737025
```

*I'm using Hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0*